# Having installed MATLAB runtime on mac I have a file.exe to run. I do not know what to do next?

Tags: macos, matlab, runtime, exe

My current version of matlab : Matlab_R2016a
I have installed the MATLAB Runtime version R2016a 9.0.1 Intel 64 bits for Mac.
My OS is 10.11.4

After installing MATLAB Runtime, the folder is in my Applications.
I have a file.exe that should be executable through MATLAB Runtime. I do not know what to do next. I was expecting some icons to launch some gui or a command line to do in matlab.
I only find the tutorials to install the Runtime but not how to execute the file with it.

What am I missing?

Comment: .exe is generally only for Windows.

Comment: You're missing the OS X equivalent of file.exe it appears; you'll either need that or install/run MATLAB within a virtual machine running Windows.

Comment: I was hoping that `mono` would be sufficient to execute my file.exe
And yes I was hoping on not using a virtual machine. Thank you for your answers

Comment: @user4404699: `mono` might work — I guess you won't know unless you try it though. Good luck!

Comment: Know it does not. Seeing the file.exe and knowing `mono` could work, I was not worried in the first place. Guess I just have the option of having the VM now.